# How to get user account name by display name

Tags: 2010, user-profile, spservices

In Sharepoint 2010 I am getting display name of the user with SPServices like `11;#John, Kondo`. But I want account name like `mydomain\aa2311`. Is there any way to get the account name with the display name property?
Not for the currently logged in user. I am having one person or group column in sharepoint list. I am getting values from this column. It is giving like `11;#John Kondo`
Following is the code :

```
 var getListItemsFrom= function(listName, viewFields, queryText, rowCount, queryOptions, asyncBool){
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            $().SPServices({
                    operation:"GetListItems",
                    async: asyncBool,
                    listName:listName,
                    CAMLRowLimit:100,
                    CAMLQuery:queryText,
                    CAMLViewFields:viewFields,
                    completefunc:function(data){
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            return deferred;
        };
getListItemsFrom("Demand Requests",viewFields ,query,0,"",true).then(function(data){
        $(data.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(ind,elm){
       var requestorAccountIds = $(this).attr('ows_Requestor');//ows_Requestor is person or group field

});
});
```

Comment: Post the code you are using

Comment: Also are you on 2010 or 2013? If 2013, I would suggest checking SP.UserProfiles http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-current-user-details-using-sharepoint-2013-csom-20687.aspx

Comment: Sorry it is in Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the user field using following code

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>"
```

Now you can extract username in success method by using string manipulation.

Comment: Not for the current user.

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: This is giving me strange result like `11;#John,, Kondo,#i:0#.w|abl\ab14431,#John.Kondo@centurylink.com,#John.Kondo@CenturyLink.com,#John,, Kondo`. It is having two commas between user display name. Do you know why?

Comment: It might be user middle name.. You can split this result usin `|` and then take the second part. Split it by comma and take first part.. tat will give you   abl\ab14431

Comment: Yeah this is fine. But if you observe display name like`11;#John,,Kondo` giving two commas. You meant to say this is happening because of middle name is empty?